# Setting Up Gmock to QT (Windows)

Tags: qt, googlemock

I'm trying unit testing using QT Creator. I tried doing it with linux and it works really fine, but when I start doing it in Windows. I discover the setting up is way different than what I did to linux.

Right now in my Windows QT Creator, I already set up gtest to my project. Everything is working fine until I started to set up googlemock. Can someone tell me how to set up googlemock in QT Creator? (windows)

I added some gmock files in the sources in my .pro file just like what I did to the gtest files. Also, I already add some library like libgmock.a and libgmock_main.a.

Here's the image of the issue results Qt

[image]

```
INCLUDEPATH += "gtest/include/"
INCLUDEPATH += "gtest/"
INCLUDEPATH += "../../"
INCLUDEPATH += "gmock/include/gmock/"
INCLUDEPATH += "gmock/include/"
INCLUDEPATH += "gmock/"
INCLUDEPATH += "../../"
FORMS += \
    ../calculator.ui
HEADERS += \
    ../calculator.h \
    ../button.h
SOURCES += \
    ../calculator.cpp \
    ../button.cpp \
    main.cpp \
    gtest/src/gtest-typed-test.cc \
    gtest/src/gtest-test-part.cc \
    gtest/src/gtest-printers.cc \
    gtest/src/gtest-port.cc \
    gtest/src/gtest-filepath.cc \
    gtest/src/gtest-death-test.cc \
    gtest/src/gtest-all.cc \
    gtest/src/gtest.cc \
    gmock/src/gmock-spec-builders.cc \
    gmock/src/gmock-matchers.cc \
    gmock/src/gmock-cardinalities.cc \
    gmock/src/gmock-all.cc \
    gmock/src/gmock.cc \
    gmock/src/gmock-internal-utils.cc
win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../Gmock_lib/ -lgmock_main
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../Gmock_lib/ -lgmock_maind
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../Gmock_lib/ -lgmock_main
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../Gmock_lib
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../Gmock_lib
win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../Gmock_lib/ -lgmock
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../Gmock_lib/ -lgmockd
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../Gmock_lib/ -lgmock
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../Gmock_lib
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../Gmock_lib
```

main.cpp

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <QApplication>
#include "Calculator/calculator.h"
#include "Calculator/button.h"
#include "Calculator/calculator.h"
#include <gmock/gmock.h>



TEST (sumInMemory, clearMemoryF) {
    calculator cal;
    double x = cal.sumInMemory;
       EXPECT_EQ( x , 0.0);
}

TEST (functionTest, Subtest1) {
    calculator cal;
   int x = cal.equalClicked();

   EXPECT_NE( x , -1);
}

TEST (functionTest, Subtest2) {
    calculator cal;
   double x = cal.factorSoFar;

   EXPECT_EQ( x , 0.0);
}


int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
            return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

Comment: Why do you add both the googlemock sources and the library to the project file ? The file "gmock-all.cc" includes all the source files necessary for googlemock.

Comment: I removed the gmock library and also the googlemock sources except to gmock-all.cc. Still not working, sir @MathiasSchmid

Comment: I add an image of the Issue Result. I hope it could help

Comment: No idea by your image. Could you provide your sources or a minimal/stripped example which shows the failing result you are facing ?

Comment: I still haven't added some gmock related codes in my main.cpp. It just happens everytime I add some "gmock/gmock.h"  header file in my main.cpp. I guess there's wrong in my sources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experienced the same problem, I suggest you to download other version of gmock. In my case I use gmock 1.7.0. Some older version have some problems/issues. Just follow what the compiler says to you.

Fix bug one step at a time

Comment: I tried the version 1.7.0, I change the items of my src and include.

Comment: There's a lot of issues I see in GMock, where there are just limited communities for it

Answer (score 1):

My new .pro file

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

CONFIG += console c++14

INCLUDEPATH += "gmock/include/"
INCLUDEPATH += "gmock/"
INCLUDEPATH += "gtest/include/"
INCLUDEPATH += "gtest/src/"
INCLUDEPATH += "gtest/"
INCLUDEPATH += "../../"

FORMS += \
    ../calculator.ui

HEADERS += \
    ../calculator.h \
    ../button.h \


SOURCES += \
    ../calculator.cpp \
    ../button.cpp \
    main.cpp \
    gtest/src/gtest.cc \
    gtest/src/gtest-all.cc \
    gtest/src/gtest-death-test.cc \
    gtest/src/gtest-filepath.cc \
    gtest/src/gtest-port.cc \
    gtest/src/gtest-printers.cc \
    gtest/src/gtest-test-part.cc \
    gtest/src/gtest-typed-test.cc
```

and the items inside my src file are

```
gmock-spec-builders.cc
gmock-matchers.cc
gmock-internal-utils.cc
gmock-cardinalities.cc
gmock-all.cc
gmock-main.cc
gmock.cc
```

note: I only use src and include for my gtest and gmock for my test file.
I hope this would help others